# How do freshen a phar cached with the phar.cache_list directive?

Tags: php, apache, phar

I added my phar to the [cache_list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php#ini.phar.cache-list) directive in `php.ini` and caching worked great. A few days later I updated the phar now I get the following error:

```
Warning: Phar::webPhar(phar:///usr/share/app/app.phar/www.php): failed to open
stream: phar error: internal corruption of phar "/usr/share/app/app.phar"
(crc32 mismatch on file "www.php") in /usr/share/app/app.phar on line 8
```

If I comment out the `cache_list` directive, the phar works and loads fine, but now I can no longer cache it. This make me think that PHP is looking at the `crc32` of the old file.

I have tried restarting apache I don't know how else to "freshen" the cache or if this is even the issue.

Comment: Have you tried with a new file name?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest deleting or renaming your old app.phar file. The system should regenerate a new one on your next load. If the same error crops up, you have one of two problems:

- One of the paths to the phars you have cached is wrong, causing the whole list to fail.
- One of the phars you are caching has no meta data, causing it to fail.

A good test for the second one is adding a piece of junk metadata(that is, if you're not already using metadata). [phar::setMetadata()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.setmetadata.php)

As usual, check all your paths.

Without a good view of the code your running or what was changed, I can't really suggest anything further.